# Outlook 2016 shows only free/busy information for my calendar when creating a new meeting

Tags: calendar, microsoft-outlook-2016

We're using Outlook 2016 and Office 365 at my organization. When I attempt to create a new meeting in Outlook 2016 (Windows 7) and view the scheduling assistant, I see only my free/busy schedule (so no details about my meetings).

When I add others to the meeting request, who have shared their calendars with me (individually or as part of a group) then I do see their additional details, as expected. (Not just whether they're free/busy, so it doesn't seem to be a rendering issue where I see free/busy for everyone.)

If I use the Office 365 web interface to create a meeting request, then I see full information about my calendar, as I would expect. So the issue seems to be with the Outlook 2016 application, or my permissions in some way.

Permissions on my calendar:

- Default: Free/Busy time, subject, location
- Anonymous: Free/Busy time
- Me: Owner

  - Read = Full Details, Delete items = All, all checkboxes selected.
  - If I view properties I can confirm that it points to my account.

I have no issues viewing, creating, updating, or deleting items in my calendar in the Windows application; I just can't see anything beyond my free/busy schedule when scheduling a meeting.

What do I need to change in order to see my own event details (not just free/busy) when scheduling a meeting request in the Windows Outlook 2016 application, like I could before?

Below is a capture of what scheduling the same block of time from the desktop and Web interfaces looks like. I would like the same amount of information shown for myself using the desktop app as I do for the web interface.

[image: Side-by-side compare of desktop and web interfaces using the same account, but showing different amounts of information.]

Comment: All I see here is a vague list of symptoms.  I don’t see a question or a problem statement.  You say that, in Office 365, you get what you expect, but you don’t say what you expect.  You say “the issue” but you don’t say what the issue is.    Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Thank you Scott for the downvote and explanation on why my question hasn't been answered over 9 months after I posted it. Because SE doesn't doesn't notify commenters of updates: I've attempted to add clarification information and would appreciate if you could let me know if that helps clarify the question. :)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that you updated the question (and for being polite about it).   I guess you’ve improved it enough for me to withdraw my downvote.   It’s still not crystal clear to me, but I’m a poor one to judge; I haven’t used Outlook in over four years, so I’ve forgotten what the interface looks like.   (BTW, this means that I probably won’t be able to answer your question; I came to this page only to review [Jesper Andén’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/1212816/150988#1308375).)   It might help if you added screenshots. Good luck!

Comment: Good idea on screenshots. I was tempted to do that in my update but figured I was on vacation and didn't really want an excuse to remote into my machine. :D

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by find out it have about the suggested user in the address field to do, pick the user in the address book by click on To field and select user and it works.

Comment: This is very hard to understand.

Comment: Jesper I've added the explicit question to the end of the post. Perhaps that helps clarify that I'm looking for a solution to the symptoms I'm describing and would result in you changing or removing your answer?

Answer (score 0):

When in Outlook 2016 select 'File' then 'Options' when the next window opens select the 'Calendar' option underneath General and Mail tab. Scroll down until you see an area for Scheduling Assistant. Verify the checkbox is checked for "Show Calendar details in Scheduling Grid."

This should now show detail when trying to setup a meeting using Scheduling Assistant feature in Outlook 2016.

Comment: Unfortunately both options are already checked. I did try unchecking both (confirming that details weren't showing for someone I had access to view) and then checked both again (confirming details were showing for that same person). That also rules out that my checkbox was in a weird half-checked state.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Outlook 2016.

After few changing around, found that ONE of the 'Out Of Office' requests that I accepted had 'Show As' option set 'Busy'. Thus Outlook considers busy all over.

In my case, it was showing busy for a 2/3 weeks, post that it was normal. So thought it has something to do with the requests, not Outlook itself.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I don't believe that's the issue as I'd still be able to see details for it for my own calendar, correct?